# deployment vue.js and webpack

Tags: deployment, webpack, vue.js

I want in my Project to use vue.js Admin panel 
so i choose this 
https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot

when i run project throw cmd >  npm run dev

its work perfect throw : localhost:8080

But i need to upload the admin panel to hosting server  (live)

so before i upload it

i run > npm run build

and upload it

but its not work correct when i open mydomain.com

its give me blank page

even in local if i try to open project like :

http://localhost/CoPilot

assume i put admin panel code in wamp/www/CoPilot

its also give me blank page

do i forget any step ?

why its only run throw localhost:8080

thank you

Comment: do you point your domains at the /dist/ folder within your project?

Comment: no
how can i do that ?

Comment: have you tried http://localhost/CoPilot/dist ? this should work for your local set up..to simplify you would have to set up a [virtual host](https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/)..and your hosted mydomain.com depends on the hoster..usually in the admin panel are settings for your domain where you can define a path

Comment: actually 
localhost/CoPilot/dist  Dont work either

Comment: the dist directory should contain index.html and a static folder, right? any errors on npm run build? what shows the browser development console and how does the source code of the page look like in the browser?

Comment: yes dist folder contain (index.html and static folder ) ,
no error in run build

Comment: and dev tools/page source code show webpack injected scripts? have you tried setting up a virtual host?

Comment: no its not injected the scripts ( when run  localhost/CoPilot/) 

but in locathost:8080 its inject correctly

Comment: this is the host 
http://deicidedeniers.com/

Comment: this work if site is locate in main directory > public-html 

what if i want to run it like /admin 
where i should change ???

Comment: can't follow..so did you solve it? are you talking about localhost or remote? depends..you could just move the content of /dist/ into /admin/ or you could rewrite using e.g. .htaccess "mod rewrite"

Answer (score 0):

In file config/index.js, change the port.

Comment: change port to what ?
assume i want to run it like this 
http://localhost/CoPilot